# WiX bootstrapper disable .NET Framework installation chaining

Tags: wix

In my WiX installer, I do not want .NET installed automatically if it isn't installed.  It should just give a warning or merely error out.

The reason to avoid it is [explained here](http://www.wrightfully.com/part-2-of-writing-your-own-net-based-installer-with-wix-creating-the-projects-in-visual-studio/):

> One HUGE word of
>   caution here:  Because the .Net installer will technically be part of
>   your install chain, if the user installs .Net but then cancels your
>   install, your installer will still be listed in the Add/Remove
>   programs since one if it’s components (the .Net installer) completed. 
>   Tread with caution.

He seems to be intentionally including it.  But I'm not and I happened to set `<supportedRuntime version="v4.5" />` which I guess isn't a real version (4.5 => 4.0 as far as this is concerned?).  My WiX managed bootstrapper application exe automatically prompted me to download and install the "missing" .NET Framework.

For computers that ARE missing 4.0, I don't want this to happen.  WiX also complains if I leave out:

```
<WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqLicenseUrl" Value="..." />
<WixVariable Id="WixMbaPrereqPackageId" Value="..." />
```

in which I literally leave in `...` because I don't want it to work anyway.

[In this thread](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Unknown-WiX-variables-in-Bundle-with-WiX-3-6-1908-0-td6574163.html), @Shruthi asks

> Is there a way to replace the prerequisite .Net install UI with just an notification to the user that they need to install a particular version of .Net before they can install the bundle?

And Rob Mensching replies:

> Yes, that is possible now.

... BUT HE DOESN'T ELABORATE.  *How* is it possible now?

Thanks!

===============

In my Bundle's Bootstrap.Config:

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v6" />  <!-- Pretending it's the future! -->
</startup>
```

[image: WiX bootstrap stub window?]

The Bundle itself does not reference any .NET stuff and does not reference `WixNetFxExtension` and uses the custom `<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="ManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost" />`

Answer (score 1):

To answer how to handle checking for the .Net 4.0 Framework include the [WixNetfxExtension](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixnetfxextension.html) in your project

then under product add a reference to the property NETFRAMEWORK40FULL and put a condition on it.

```
<PropertyRef Id="NETFRAMEWORK40FULL"/>
<Condition Message="This application requires .NET Framework 4.0. Please install the .NET Framework then run this installer again.">
  <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK40FULL]]>
</Condition>
```

for the chained case again include wixnetfxextension and include NetFx40Redist package group

```
<PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Redist"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have that in the MSI project, but this is something that seems to me to be happening as part of the Bundle's logic.  Do you think that's wrong?

Comment: Oh, so you're bundling your MSI with the .Net framework? If that's the case then use NetFx40Redist from the WixNetfxExtenion in your chain.

Comment: Hi Rick - I mean to NOT bundle it.  I just want it to be a requirement, but not include it in the chain of things that can be installed by this installer.

Comment: If you don't want it bundled then remove the references to it in your bundle, it won't be installed then. When your MSI is executed you said there's a condition checking for it so if a user does not have it installed they will be notified there.

Comment: Hi Rick, please see my additions to the original post explaining that I'm already following that advice, I believe.

Comment: I've not used a managed bootstrapper, this looks like it might be helpful though http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/WixManagedBootstrapperApplicationHost-and-NET-2-0-td7581333.html

Comment: That does seem related.  What I get from it is that I should remove that node from the Bootstrap.Config altogether!  But I'm not sure I can trust that idea - it was his own guess and it was not validated.